# Dispatch type for custom middleware in redux

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux toolkit, and have created a thunk using createAsyncThunk that gets called from a middleware (code below). What is the correct dispatch type? Right now it only works if I specify "any".

```
import { Action, Dispatch } from "redux";
import { updateTerm } from "../slices/explore";

const middleWare = ({ dispatch }: { dispatch: Dispatch<Action> }) => {
  return (next: (action: Action) => void) => {
    return (action: Action) => {
      next(action);
      if (updateTerm.match(action)) {       
          dispatch<any>(getShows(action.payload)); 
      }
    };
  };
};

const getShows = createAsyncThunk<
  Show[],
  string,
  { rejectValue: SearchError }
>("explore/getShows", async (term: string, { rejectWithValue }) => {
 //do async stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you would need to use the `ThunkDispatch` type from the `redux-thunk` library.

Ideally, you *wouldn't* reference that at all, and instead use [the AppDispatch`type inferred from`store.dispatch`](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types).  However, because this is a middleware, and middleware themselves alter the type of` store.dispatch`, you'd end up with a circular type definition problem.

Having said that, I'd actually recommend *not* writing a custom middleware here, especially for just dispatching one action.

Instead, I'd recommend using [the new "listener middleware" that will be out in the next version of Redux Toolkit](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/1648).  It's currently available as a standalone `@rtk-incubator/action-listener-middleware` package.